# The argument type 'x' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'y'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

There is a problem with this line

```
Text(snapshot.data.isPause);
```

I don't know how to fix it.

-----------------------------------------CODE-------------------------------------------

```
MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<Post>(
            future: fetchPost(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData)
                return Text(snapshot.data.isPause);
              else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }),
      )),
    )
```

---

The argument type `x` can't be assigned to the parameter type `y`

Comment: What `isPause` is returning?

Answer (score 1):

Your `isPause` isn't returning `String`, it needs to return `String` because `Text()` accepts `String`, for quick hack, you can try below solution.

```
Text(snapshot.data.isPause.toString());
```

Comment: in my phone the Application says -> type'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a sub type 'List<dynamic>'.

Comment: Can you post `fetchPost()` method?

Comment: Future<Post> fetchPost() async {
  final responce =
      await http.get("API link");

  if (responce.statusCode == 200) {
    return Post.fromJson(json.decode(responce.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load...!');
  }
}

Comment: class Post {
  final bool autoPlay;
  final bool isPause;

  final List nowPlaying;
  final List queue;

  final double volume;

  Post({
    this.autoPlay,
    this.isPause,
    this.nowPlaying,
    this.queue,
    this.volume,
  });

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      autoPlay: json['auto_play'],
      isPause: json['is_pause'],
      nowPlaying: json['now_playing'],
      queue: json['queue'],
      volume: json['volume'],
    );
  }
}

Comment: @Sadisha please update your question. Can you even read the commented code?

Comment: @Sadisha I think the case is your API returning List of data but you are trying `Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)`. First check your json structure.